# How to access the SVNClientAdapter that subclipse is using during runtime?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, listener, subclipse

I am using the Subclipse API and I would like to implement the ISVNNotifyListener so that I can find out about the subclipse events as they happen during runtime. I believe I need to add (subscribe) my instance of the notify listener to the set of listeners that the Client Adapter will notify, but I am at a loss for how to get access to the Client Adapter that is being used by Subclipse at runtime. Is there a way to access it so that I can add my listener to the set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but unfortunately Subclipse has not been coded in such a way to provide access to the internals.  Subclipse constructs a new ISVNClientAdapter object for each API call it needs to make into Subversion and it adds its ISVNNotifyListener to this object on the fly as needed.  So there is no way for you to interject your own listener.

Perhaps you could write a class that implements IConsoleListener and have it act as a proxy for the Subclipse class.  You could then call SVNProviderPlugin.getConsoleListener to get the current console listener and store a reference to it in your class.  Then call SVNProviderPlugin.setConsoleListener to replace the class held in Subclipse with your class.  As the events are fired in your class, you could just forward them on to the Subclipse class and do whatever you want with the events in your code.  Something like this:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.client.IConsoleListener;
import org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNNodeKind;

public class ProxyListener implements IConsoleListener {

    private IConsoleListener subclipseListener;

    public ProxyListener(IConsoleListener subclipseListener) {
        super();
        this.subclipseListener = subclipseListener;
    }


    public void setCommand(int command) {
        subclipseListener.setCommand(command);
        // TODO add your code

    }

    public void logCommandLine(String commandLine) {
        subclipseListener.logCommandLine(commandLine);
        // TODO add your code

    }

    public void logMessage(String message) {
        subclipseListener.logMessage(message);
        // TODO add your code

    }

    public void logError(String message) {
        subclipseListener.logError(message);
        // TODO add your code

    }

    public void logRevision(long revision, String path) {
        subclipseListener.logRevision(revision , path);
        // TODO add your code

    }

    public void logCompleted(String message) {
        subclipseListener.logCompleted(message);
        // TODO add your code

    }

    public void onNotify(File path, SVNNodeKind kind) {
        subclipseListener.onNotify(path, kind);
        // TODO add your code

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I have something just like this setup in my plugin. I additionally throw the initial consoleListener in a temp and then set 'this' (which is a console listener) as the console listener of the SVNProviderPlugin. However, as I am testing my plugin and doing various subclipse commands such as commits, the print statements that I have put in setCommand, onNotify, etc. don't get written to the console. Any ideas why my implementation of the console listener isn't getting notified of these events?

Comment: Also, you mentioned forwarding the events on to the Subclipse class (I assume you mean the default IConsoleListener that I have pulled out of the SVNProviderPlugin). Is this something that needs to be done for Subclipse to function normally? In other words, I don't want to disrupt Subclipse's functionality, I just want to be able to find out about the subclipse events as they happen in real time.

Comment: In the example I gave above you would be REPLACING the one that Subclipse provides with your class.  If your class does not act as a proxy and forward the calls to Subclipse's class, then it cannot do what it was intended to do.  In this case, the Subclipse class handles writing the results to the Eclipse console.  BTW, the Eclipse console is not stdout.  So you cannot simply "print" to add something to it.  You would have to write Eclipse SWT code to output information somewhere you can see it.  If you are writing to stdout, then it will show up in the Eclipse .log and you can see it there.

Comment: So I am launching/deploying my plugin from Eclipse by doing 'Run As' -> 'Eclipse Application' on the plugin project. It starts a new Eclipse workspace, but I expect output from my prints to show up in the console of the original Eclipse workspace. I see my print statements from other areas of the plugin, but my print statements that are in methods like setCommand of my ProxyListener simply aren't appearing when I execute subclipse commands from the deployed WS. I think my listener simply isn't getting notified. Do you know why this would be? SVNProviderPlugin is set to use my ProxyListener.

Comment: If you do not see any output then your code must not be getting called.  I would check the SVNProviderPlugin object and see if your class is set as the console listener.  Maybe you set your listener before the Subclipse UI plugin did and it replaced yours.  Or maybe this idea just does not work.

Comment: Hmm, think I found the problem. Sometimes the SVNProviderPlugin hasn't been fully initialized by the time I go to initialize my ProxyListener, so I think it was getting overwritten like you said. My solution was to put a call SVNProviderPlugin.getPlugin(); in the ProxyListener's constructor. This seems to insure that the SVNProviderPlugin has been started before I swap out the IConsoleListeners. Do you think this is a good fix or just a hack?

Comment: I would suggest you call this: SVNUIPlugin.getPlugin().enableConsoleListener();  Unfortunately, I see there is also a disableConsoleListner() that nulls out the value. So this means the UI plugin may eventually remove your listener.  it is currently only called from the set property UI though.

Comment: We should move this to the dev@subclipse.tigris.org mailing list if you have more questions