# subclipse or eclipse team action listener

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I am creating a plugin and I would like to execute some code after a subclipse revert. But I cant't find how to detect such thing. 
So far I have tried registering a listener at startup like this:

```
ISVNClientAdapter client = null;
try {
    client = SVNProviderPlugin.getPlugin().getSVNClientManager().getSVNClient();
    client.addNotifyListener(listener);
} catch (Exception e) {}
finally {
    SVNProviderPlugin.getPlugin().getSVNClientManager().returnSVNClient(client);
}
```

The listener is certainly registered (I checked with the debugger), but methods are not called in it for any svn action.

Does anyone know how to listen for subclipse or team actions?

Comment: See this previous answer and the comments:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518467/how-to-access-the-svnclientadapter-that-subclipse-is-using-during-runtime/7520513#7520513

Comment: Yes that works! Thanks!